How to detect ERC-4437 Ethereum transfers
I have an address I'm monitoring and for straight Eth transfers its simple but I am struggling to detect ERC-4337 transfers.
I can filter on user operation events:
const USER_OPERATION_EVENT = id('UserOperationEvent(bytes32,address,address,uint256,bool,uint256,uint256)')

The issue is a single user operation event doesn't tell me everything. Like lets look at the logs of a random transaction:
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3b18399bedc88774e303b5f278ed549e22b4a45a97452c72bedaff419fa3fd58#eventlog
I have the sender but no amount or receiver address.
Etherscan doesn't seem to struggle with this though and gives a nice summary of whats happening.

If I understand your question correctly, I believe the answer lies in the way ERC4337 transfers are executed.
This pattern sees a variety of contracts implemented to achieve the functionality of account abstraction. Basically it means that we have a variety of outputs from a variety of contracts given a user input.
If we look at the second log, it shows the account and totalDeposit, just executed from a different address (likely the entry point, a common and essential, off shelf component for any implementation of 4337).
The answer you're looking for relies on taking the account address and finding associated logs from the entry point contract for this caller. That will provide you with the amounts moving around, plus other metadatas.
